# How to get breakable axis in JFreeChart?

Tags: java, jfreechart

We are plotting graph using JFreeChart, and for y-axis we have set auto range as false. Instead, we set the range by taking the min and max value of dataset. For example, the min and max values from dataset as 64 and 160000 respectively; but the scale is set in step of 10000 so we could not see the min value in the graph. The scale is set based on the max value. Is there a way to accommodate both min and max value in the graph with some breaks in between where there are no data to plot?

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for a chart with a logarithmic y-axis?

Comment: In logarithmic y-axis the granularity is high . We want to show all values in the graph with less granularity.Is there an option in JFreechart to have a breaks like if there are no values between 10000 to 90000 then we can skip those values?

Comment: If you skip y-axis values, the chart looks distorted.  You could scale your Y values in some manner if you want, but you need to be clear to the viewer of the chart what you're doing.

Comment: Like @GilbertLeBlanc, I don't see any support for this; some alternatives are shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44151032/230513).